# Testing randomness of VBA rnd function

Tags: excel, vba, random

I am using the VBA random function rnd() 
in a Monte Carlo simulation to get normal and rectangular distributed pseudo random numbers. 
In a text book about Monte Carlo I found that one should test random number generators for  their randomness. I found some information about testing, like diehard or TestU01. But actually I don't know how to use them.
Is there a simple method to test it?

Comment: How do you think you should measure randomness?

Comment: I thought there are certain statistical test, aren't?

Comment: Maybe knowing how diehard or TestU01 work would help me.

Comment: Maybe. Perhaps you should research them and when you have attempted to write your own code, and you get stuck, then ask us how to fix your code. That's what we're good at. We're not a proxy for Google.